# Drop down navigation in menu tucking under another drop down in WordPress

Tags: css, wordpress, drop-down-menu

There are 2 menus in the following site:

http://lastshredsofsanity.com/

I am not sure why this theme is being used this way, but it is how the person made their site. I had fixed this issue before and somehow 3 days later the top menu, when you hover for the child pages, it goes under the second navigation menu. (If you hover over the Shewed Designs, you will see what I mean.)

Now, I thought this was a z-index issue. However, I've tried.

I must not be seeing it, as this is a simple CSS fix and I asked my friend to not touch the CSS until this issue is fixed.

I checked Google and Stack overflow, applied a couple suggestions, but to no avail, I think I am just a little too close at the moment to the project and missing something so simple it  is nearly stupid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what order you're loading your CSS files, but `#catnav` has a `z-index` of 999, whilst `#topnav` is never assigned a `z-index` value greater than 5. Since they are both id'd elements, I think the specificity is equal on both, so it becomes an instance of "last rule applied wins." To test this, you could add an embedded `style` attribute to the #topnav `<ul>` element with a z-index rule that is higher, like 9999.

HTH.

Comment: It was the fact that the z-index was set at 5 for both on the custom file!!! And I totally missed it. I went and compared the original theme's CSS to comb over it and compare with the changes... then found what you were talking about with the z-index:5;Thank you!!!!